# On Keyup values are being parsed. How to set those values in jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am retriving Bing values from it's api through this link:

http://api.bing.net/qson.aspx?Query=s&Market=en-us&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=

Now when I parse the results on keyup and append them in the body it works but when I set the results on jQuery's autocomplete it doesn't.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkVcg/

NOTE: In the fiddle I've also included Yahoo's auto suggest which uses the same method so that I can proof that it should work.

What I'm I doing wrong? **How can I make the results of Bing to appear on jQuery's autocomplete()?**

Comment: Have you even looked at the developer console? it's full of errors.

Comment: I did. There is one error: "HTTP Version not supported" where on keyUp it is supported? Plus I tried different ways onto setting the keyup version to autocomplete still with no results

Comment: There was also cannot read property length

Comment: I don't get that one in chrome dev tools. Is there anything wrong with the code? Or is it not possible to take those parsed items and set them in an autocomplete?

Comment: @Esailija I'm not seeing any errors in Firebug.  I do see the 505 error however. The HTTP request parameters look quite different when encoded by jQuery (that is, when passed in as the "data" object as in the autocomplete "source" handler instead of in the URL).

Comment: Please post your code in the question.  It makes SO more searchable when people have a similar problem in the future, and it makes SO more self-contained in case the third-party site goes down.  But feel free to also keep the link, as jsfiddle.net is a great tool for getting answers quickly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkVcg/12/) is a working version of the fiddle.

There were 2 key changes:

1. I set up the URL and parameters as in your "keyup" version. That fixed the 505.
2. You were referencing "val.key" in the "success" handler instead of "val.Text" as in your "keyup" code.

Thus:

```
$("#bing_auto").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        console.log("source");
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.bing.net/qson.aspx?Query=" + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + "&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            /*data: {
                "Query": request.term,
                "JsonType": "callback",
                "JsonCallback" : "?"
            },*/


            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success!");
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data.SearchSuggestion.Section, function (i, val) {
                    console.log("suggestion: " + val.Text);
                    suggestions.push(val.Text);
                });
                response(suggestions);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

(Take out the "console.log()" calls if you like :-)

Comment: On the "bing keyup" I'm getting showered with `9
jquery-1.7.1.js:630Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` I'm on google chrome on Firefox 7 I get: `[17:13:27.046] object is undefined @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js:630`

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox 8 on Linux; I get no errors at all.

Comment: You can imagine how long it took me sir. and it works perfectly on all browsers for me

Comment: Well I get it in the keyup if the field is empty; just needs a check for that. However when it's not empty it seems fine.

Comment: @Pointy, I just open up console and write "asdasd" one key at a time, and get error for each .. :/ * shrug * In firefox7 and chrome on 12th revision of the fiddle

Comment: That's odd.  I just tried Chrome (15) and it seems fine too. I haven't personally started using jQuery 1.7 so I don't have much experience with it; it would be surprising for it to be so fragile however.